# Autostart ControlExtension on Smartwatch 2

Tags: android, sony, autostart, sony-smartwatch, sony-xperia

I am trying a to make a simple watch for smartwatch 2. I want to autostart my app when the smartwatch screen awakes.
I dont want sony watch faces to appear when then screen is turned on.
How to implement this. I found the feature in [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kaybit.smartwatch.customwatch).

Answer (score 0):

The first problem you will have is that Sony Smartwatch 2's screen never goes off.. it lights up or dims but never goes off.

The link you provide is for a Smartwatch 1 watch. That one did turn off the screen because it wasn't transflective as the SW 2 is.

Cheers

Comment: He says in his description
Does the Custom Watch replace the native watch?
Answer:
No. Nobody can replace the native watch.
But we implemented an autostart option for Custom Watch on SmartWatch 2. This means Custom Watch will start automatically so it will almost feel like the native watch.